# Problem in fetching api in react native while working fine in postman

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

I'm developing a react-native app on 
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.1"

i have api published on some remote server while fetching those api it's giving me TypeError: network request error

while my api is working fine on postman

```
await fetch(
        "https://57.17.239.178:8087/api/accounts/Login",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
            // 'Authorization':''
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            userName: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
          })
        }
      )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
          console.log(responseJson);
          localStorage.saveUserSession(
            this.state.email,
            this.state.password,
            responseJson.tokenString,
            responseJson.role,
            responseJson.expiresOn
          );
          this.setState({
            email: "",
            password: "",
            activityIndicator_boolean: "false"
          });
          this.props.navigation.navigate("DashBoard");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          alert(error);
          this.setState({
            activityIndicator_boolean: false
          });
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Its giving me TypeError: network request error

Debugging on a physical device with android 7.0

and using android sdk 28

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your physical device can reach the url `https://57.17.239.178:8087/api/accounts/Login` by accessing by your mobile browser.

Probably the device can't access unless you connect it to the same network that your computer is.

Comment: can you kindly elaborate this please ? because i can hit this api from postman. if it is accessible from postman why it is not accessible from my debugging phone ?